# remove div element from many div elements using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

how to hide/remove a div from many div being generated using jquery on click ? below code for repeating boxed:

```
var el = $("div");
  var bottom = $(window).height();
  while (el.offset().top + el.height() < bottom) {
    el = el.clone().insertAfter(el);
```

i am trying to hide/remove the div element using below but its not working ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: There is nothing in the above code to remove *anything*. Lookup http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Example HTML/DOM please? `this` refers to the `p` element not a `div` element. Post your structure and explain which element you want to remove if another element is clicked. We cannot read minds (well, not all of us).

Comment: You don't have any code that removes divs; you only have code that removes (well, hides) `<p>`.  What is your goal?

Comment: hide just hides the element.. not remove..

Comment: have made changes in the question for making it clear....please help

Comment: code makes no sense... you create element...then immediately remove it

Comment: @charlietfl The element is cloned before being removed... Still no idea why...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work because the element is dynamically generated... try...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', 'div', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

Comment: It's `$(document).on()` not `document.on()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a classname to differentiate the clones.

```
el = el.clone().addClass("clone").insertAfter(el);
```

And use delegation over `.clone`.

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click", ".clone", function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

[**See it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cvud8/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason, you're code isn't working, might be a timing issue. If your `$(document).ready(...)` is executed *before* your `<script>...</script>`, it won't find all the dynamically generated `div`s.

If you really want to remove the div's, which where clicked on

HTML:

```
<div>Sample</div>
```

JS:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  var el = $("div");
  var bottom = $(window).height();
  while (el.offset().top + el.height() < bottom) {
    el = el.clone().insertAfter(el);
  }

  el.remove();

  $('div').click(function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yJms2/) for testing.